# Is there a way to get the monophone probability using HTK?

Tags: speech-recognition, htk

Ideally what I am looking for is a way to get a vector of probability that a particular segment of an audio file is a certain phone. Something like:

input:

- wavfile
- start position (e.g. @1.4 sec)
- duration (e.g. 500 ms)

output:

- SIL 2.324*10^-3
- AA  1.514*10^-4
- AE  1.482*10^-2
- ...
- ZH  5.03*10^-5

Comment: May I ask you what exactly are you trying to do? It is quite unusual to estimate a single monophone probability for such a long segment. Also, the probabilities will be represented in log scale, as their values will be very tiny and cause underflow.

Comment: Are you aiming just on acoustic score or combined with a language model?

Comment: @Dmytro Prylipko Thank you for the reply, the numbers used to illustrate the use case were bad examples. I would be running this on much shorter segments and I understand it would be in log scale. I am only looking for the acoustic scores, it would be independent of the LM, I am trying to use these scores to generate a metric for phoneme level pronunciation accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the scores running `HVite` in forced alignment mode. I am afraid you have to run this for every phoneme you have:

```
HVite -A -D -T 1 -l '*' -o NTW -C HTK.cfg -a \
    -H macros \
    -H hmmdefs \
    -i acoustic_score_AA.mlf \
    -y lab \
    -I AA.mlf \
    -S index.scp \
    words phones
```

The output file `acoustic_score_AA.mlf` will contain the result. I

The contents of `words` vocabulary file should be like:

```
AA AA
AE AE
....
ZH ZH
```

and the `phones` has to contain the list of the phonemes (HMM models), as far as I remember.

The trick here is the content of the input .mlf file. For instance, `AA.mlf` should be like:

```
#!MLF!#
"*/S0001.lab"
AA
.
```

This will force HVite to apply the `AA` model for the whole utterance. Chunking of the audio file has to be performed in advance.

Comment: Thank you, Dmytro!